# How to efficiently find group strings containing another string in a string array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

For an array like:

```
["abc", "bc", "dd", "d", "ee", "ff", "e"]
```

What would be an efficient way to get:

```
[["abc", "bc"],["dd", "d"],["ee", "e"]]
```

**Explanation**

```
["abc", "bc"] because "abc" contains "bc" 
["dd", "d"] because "dd" contains "d"
["ee", "e"] because "ee" contains "e"
```

Any new method including parallelism is also welcomed.

Comment: What if the array contains `"bce"`?

Comment: Sorry, could you please explain the logic behind the supposed input/output?

Comment: What have **YOU** tried so far? Share your research findings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using `reduce()`. Check if the element is included by other element. If not then add it as key of accumulator. If its included then add it to that array. At last use `Object.values()` to get values(arrays). Use `filter()` to remove arrays having `length = 1`

```js
let arr = ["abc", "bc", "dd", "d", "ee", "ff", "e"] 

let res = Object.values(arr.reduce((ac,a,i) => {
  
  if(!arr.some((x,b) => x.includes(a) && i !== b)) ac[a] = [a];
  else {
    for(let k in ac){
      if(k.includes(a)){
        ac[k].push(a)
        break;
      }
      
    }
  }
  return ac;

},{})).filter(x => x.length -1)

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop in reverse direction and using the function `splice` you can drop the element and push it into the current array.

```js
let arr = ["abc", "bc", "dd", "d", "ee", "ff", "e"];
let result = [];
for (let i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  let target = arr.splice(i, 1).pop();
  if (target === undefined) continue;
  
  let current = [target],
      index = 0;
  while ((index = arr.findIndex(s => s.includes(target))) != -1) {
    current.push(arr[index]);
    arr.splice(index, 1);
  }
  
  if (current.length > 1) result.push(current);
}

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```